# displaying a matplotlib figure from a custom class in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I have a wrapper class that contains a `matplotlib.figure.Figure` object:

```
class FigureData:
   def __init__(self, figure, metadata=None):
       self.figure = figure
       self.metadata = metadata

   def __repr_svg__(self):
       return self.figure
```

What I want is that when I am in Jupyter notebook, doing

```
display(figure_data)
```

Will display the figure, same as doing

```
display(figure_data.figure)
```

The second command works, the first one doesn't. I thought implementing `__repr_svg__` would help but I obviously don't understand the underlying mechanics of `display`.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be combination of two errors:

1. The name `__repr_svg__` is wrong, it should be `_repr_svg_`
2. Matplotlib's `Figure` should be converted to svg if we want to use it as svg. The `_repr_svg_` method should return an `str` representation of the svg.